# p4 unshelve results in "rename: ... Permission denied"

Tags: perforce, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use `p4` under WSL on Windows 10. I can normally use other operations from open files for editing to shelving, etc.

Now I have my own shelved changelist i.e. `12345`, and current state of my workspace is clean. I want to unshelve all shelved files inside such changelist into the local workspace. I execute with the following command

```
p4 unshelve -s 12345
```

The result is similar to the following for each file

```
//depot/mydir/myfile#22 - unshelved, opened for edit
... //depot/mydir/myfile#22 - also opened by someone@someone_at_work
rename: /mnt/d/mydir/myfile: Permission denied
```

I tried with `strace p4 unshelve -s 12345` and it seems like it tried to create a temporary file, `chmod` it, then finally try to rename temporary file into the actual file name as seen in workspace. The last step has "-1 EACCES (Permission Denied)" similar to the following

```
chmod("/mnt/d/mydir/tmp.1648.139747365556800.93", 0666) = 0
stat("/mnt/d/mydir/tmp.1648.139747365556800.93", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=16367, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2326, ...}) = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2326, ...}) = 0
read(4, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(4, 347, SEEK_CUR)                 = 859
read(4, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
read(4, ".\204\313\220\0\0\0\0/t\274\220\0\0\0\0000d\255\220\0\0\0\0001]\331\20\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
read(4, "j\335T\220\0\0\0\0k\250[\220\0\0\0\0l\306q\20\0\0\0\0m\210=\220\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 443
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2326, ...}) = 0
rename("/mnt/d/mydir/tmp.1648.139747365556800.93", "/mnt/d/mydir/myfile") = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "rename: /mnt/d/mydir/m"..., 90rename: /mnt/d/mydir/myfile: Permission denied
) = 90
brk(0x1b40000)                          = 0x1b40000
unlink("/mnt/d/mydir/tmp.1648.139747365556800.93") = 0
unlink("/mnt/d/mydir/tmp.1648.139747365556800.93") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(0x1b30000)                          = 0x1b30000
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1596130958, tv_usec=871360}, NULL) = 0
```

Despite possibly knowing what the root cause might be but I have no clue what I can do to make `p4` works. Note that my WSL username is different from P4 username.

**Update**:

This WSL [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5019) is very close to my problem and probably it is for the compatibility between WSL and p4 at this point. Thanks to Samwise in the comment for pointing out into proper direction as well.

---

**Update 2**:

The workaround I found is to

- Open all files for edit as listed in shelved changelist
- Unshelve the files from shelved changelist

With this, we need to do some cleanup to get actual clean file name. 3 steps needed as follows.

- `p4 files @=12345 | sed 's/#.*//g' | cut -d'/' -f5- | xargs -n 1 -I{} p4 edit -c 12345 {}` (get list of files from changelist, remove unrelevant part, remove first two components in file path, then one by one edit such file into changelist of our shelved file `12345`). Note: We can also remove `cut -d'/' -f5-` out as I tested it, it still works fine. Your streams/views path might be complicated thus `-f5-` won't be able to cover for all cases.
- `p4 unshelve -s 12345`
- `p4 resolve -af` (or `at` to get theirs changes, or `ay` to only get yours)

PS: it's important to use `edit -c <changelist>` as if you edit into default changelist, you won't be able to shelve all files updating it again as perfoce cannot detect any shelved files associated with that changelist.

---

**Update 3**:
If use WSL(1 or 2), then we can avoid applying workarounds by directly using `p4.exe` and work logically with Windows filesystem. To make this works, your `Root:` property as seen in `p4.exe client` needs to be modified to based on Windows filesystem. Then continue using `p4.exe` for all other commands.

Comment: Did you build the `p4` binary yourself from source and link it against WSL libraries, or are you using prebuilt binaries that don't necessarily support WSL?  If the latter, I'd try the former; you can get the source from workshop.perforce.com.  I haven't used WSL, but I remember there used to be a custom build of `p4` for Cygwin that was necessary to handle Cygwin's ACL implementation and I'd suspect something similar is needed here.

Comment: @Samwise That is very good question. I downloaded from this [url](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4) but chosen for Linux x86 platform. Then manually install into WSL. I'm trying Cygwin now...

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough about WSL to know for sure how good the compatibility is between it and other Linux distros, but it seems like a potential issue.

Comment: `p4` on Cygwin seems outdated and there is no package available for that inside Cygwin package to download. `p4` source has internal 500 error that prevents users to download source code, not sure you have to register as a member in which I need to send an email. Thank you btw for putting me into a proper direction. I keep looking at the meantime.

Comment: You should be able to just point a p4 client at the workshop server and `p4 sync` without registering an account.

Comment: @Samwise Thank you. I will try that possibly this weekend or next one.